# How to preserve image quality with reduced size in Adobe Photoshop PDF output

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, image-quality, file-size

i'm a newbie in photoshop and i want to create a PDF output from my PSD file , the problem is when i set `best settings` in save as PDF i get a very good quality but the file is a little big about 8MB for the pdf ==> i don't know if the printer can print this file because it's take a time to get loaded in a pdf reader (adobe & foxit)

the second solution i have done is by choosing to save as pdf in `minimal size` i get less than 1 mb for the pdf but the image quality is terrible

***update*** : the document that i'm working in is a CV/RESUME so i need to post it on the web for jobs interviews that way i need less size for the outputted PDF.
Any hints ?  thanks .

Comment: 8mb isn't a very big file size and you should be able to send that document to the printer. Have you tried sending the file to print yet?

Comment: We are used to handle files some hundreds of Mb.

Comment: @AndrewH i don't know i haven't a printer i must try this later , i have said that because the file does not loaded smoothly in a pdf reader (i have 8 gb of ram)

Comment: @Rafael what you mean plz !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with print production, file size (kb) is generally not even looked at. It's unimportant. Print files will **always** be larger and it really doesn't matter how large they are.

8MB is nothing. Print production PDFs can easily reach three or four figure MB ranges for file sizes.

**The notion that all files need to be small is purely a web/UI notion.** There's no need to concern yourself at all with the file size of a PDF for print production other than *perhaps* "can you send this" via email/FTP/upload forms, etc. (Some email servers have restrictions on file sizes, that's really the only concern there'd be.)

The reality is a print-production PDF which is *too small* could be an indicator of an incorrectly formatted PDF. Not in most cases, but that can be a reality at times.

Comment: yes i have forgot to mention that the document is a CV/RESUME so i have to post it on the web for job interviews ... so what can i do in this case , thanks

Comment: Well, you really shouldn't use Photoshop to create a CV/Resume. It's just not the correct tool for that job.

Comment: But i have found plenty of CV templates using PSD files it's my first time using photoshop  , so what should i use ?

Comment: Uhm.. just because someone created a template it doesn't mean it's useful.  Word or a layout application (InDesign/Illustrator) is much more appropriate than a photo editing application. In the design industry people can and will inspect your CV/Resume PDF and actually SEE what application created it. That actually can factor into your standing for some employers. If you aren't seeking a design position... then I guess it really doesn't matter. Just use whatever PDF settings you feel work well.

Comment: well i have never used Adobe Illustrator or InDesign , if i use it ...  will i be facing the pdf size problem or not ?

Comment: what do you think please

Comment: If you aren't a designer, or applying for a design position *it doesn't matter*. If you *are* a designer or applying for a design position, you should know Illustrator at a minimum and depending upon the position, knowing InDesign may also be required.

Comment: no i'm not a designer , i just want to know if using illustrator or inDesign i can produce PDF with good image quality and reduced size ? i hope you understund what i mean , i'm not a native english speaker

Comment: Just about anything will produce a smaller PDF than a photo editing application. Your English is fine :)

Comment: so adobe illustrator can be a good choice ?

Comment: When I save High Quality Print file, which is basically a large collage made from images in single rasterised layer, (disabled Photoshop compatibility), my PDF size is around 300 MB. And If I import same as TIFF in illustrator and save High quality print file, it is around 97 MB. Does illustrator saves print PDFs better? I've problem with large PDFs and I don't understand why such a big difference. Any idea @Scott?